# Getting first values with index in Series

Tags: python, pandas

Given

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'lowercase':['a','b','c','d']},
                       index=[0,1,3,4])

# print(df)

print(df['lowercase'].iat[0])
```

I can get `'a'`, but I want to get the first index (which is `0`) and `'a'` return as two values, how should I do?

Comment: Use `df.index[0]`

Comment: `df.index[0]` ?  what do you mean by `and 'a' return as two values,` ?

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston @anky
`a=df['lowercase'].index[0]
b=df['lowercase'].iat[0]`
Can this be simplify in one line?

Comment: `a, b = df['lowercase'].index[0], df['lowercase'].iat[0]`? It's one line :)

Comment: `a,b = [*df['lowercase'].head(1).items()][0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) which returns a map object.

```
def get_item(idx):
    it = df.itertuples()
    while idx:
        next(it)
        idx = idx-1
    return next(it)

a,b = get_item(0)
# a = 0 , b = 'a'
c,d = get _item(1)
# c = 1, d = 'b'
```

You can even get a slice using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from itertools.

```
def get_item(start,end=None):
    it = df.itertuples()
    if end is None:
        while idx:
            next(it)
            idx = idx-1
        return next(it)
    return list(map(tuple,islice(it,start,end)))

get_item(1, 4)
# [(1, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

If you only want first value

```
a,b = next(df.itertuples())
# a = 0, b = 'a'
```